# Android : startSupportActionMode(actionModeCallback); Crashing for devices of version 5 and Above

Tags: java, android, toolbar

I am using ActionMode.CallBack for multiple selection in Android. startSupportActionMode() is working fine below Android version 5.0 but 5.0 and above it is crashing. Below is the crash result.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class
android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContextView
06-06 21:11:05.699 26179-26179/com.app.hab W/System.err: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContextView
06-06 21:11:05.699 26179-26179/com.app.hab W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-06 21:11:05.699 26179-26179/com.app.hab W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
06-06 21:11:05.699 26179-26179/com.app.hab W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
```

Comment: It is working fine for devices below version 5

Comment: The issue has been resolved. I was using vector resource in the style for ActionMode. Android version 5 and above does not support vector resources without gradle entry, in the style.